# Buildfire - Save an image on the widget

Tags: buildfire

I'm trying to allow a user to save an image via the widget. I'm using the function below:

```
buildfire.services.camera.getPicture({},
  function (err, imageData) {
    if (imageData) {
      document.getElementById("imgPic").src = imageData;
    } else {
      console.log("no image selected: " + err);
    }
  }
);
```

**imageData** results in a local link from the user's phone, something like:

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.buildfire.previewer/cache/1503099575571.jpg
```

If I run it through the resizer (**buildfire.imageLib.resizeImage**) I get something like this:

```
http://czi3m2qn.cloudimg.io/s/width/1600/file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.buildfire.previewer/cache/1503104990327.jpg
```

Not sure if this link is safe or if it gets garbage collected later on..

How do I save the actual image the camera takes to buildfire's database?

**EDIT:**

As you suggested, I'm using html2canvas to save my image. I load my local image to the DOM, and before I try to save, I process it like this:

```
onrendered: canvas => {
  const img = canvas.toDataURL();
  imageList.push(img);
}
```

My image is turned into a canvas, then I run toDataURL(). But when I try to save this very long image data string, it doesn't save.

[image]

In the first pink box you can see my data before I save it to buildfire. In the second pink box you can see the result of my buildfire query. I did not receive an error but the data for **images** did not save. To validate that the data was saved successfully the teal boxes match each other. It seems like the string might be too large to save?

Comment: Just to be clear. After you manipulate the image and convert it to base64 you want to send it to the BuildFire UserData or PublicData to save?

Comment: @Daniel_Madain publicData. buildfire.publicData.update() is what I'm using to be exact

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this wont work. Here is why. BuildFire uses an image manipulation server to make these changes before an image is downloaded. So you send the Image Manipulation server a url to the Raw image so that it can pull it and resize it. However, since your image is local there is no way for our Image Server to get access to it.

A better approach is using a local implementation using html5 canvas

here is an example implementation:

```
if (localURL) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = localURL;
    img.onload = function () {

        if (options.width && !options.height)
            options.height = (img.height * options.width) / img.width;
        else if (!options.width && options.height)
            options.width = (img.width * options.height) / img.width;

        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.width = options.width;
        canvas.height = options.height;


        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, options.width, options.height);

        callback(null, canvas.toDataURL());
    };
    img.onerror = function () {
        callback(null, buildfire.imageLib.resizeImage(url, options));
    }
}
```

A `crop` implementation is more complex than a resize. But there are libraries out there that do a great job like `SmartCrop.js` https://github.com/jwagner/smartcrop.js/

hope this helps

Comment: Can you check out my edit. It seems that the result from dataToURL() is too big for buildfire to save

Comment: I also tried to make the dataURL into a blob. That didn't save either

Comment: again are you trying to save the image or just show it? If you are saving it in `datastore` from the `widget` you cannot because it is read-only on the widget side. If you are using `userData` or `publicData` then you have some restrictions on size. If you are displaying the new image as a  new `src` then make sure it starts with something like `src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA...`

Comment: I responded to your comment you made on my post that I was using publicData in an attempt to save. The image I posted shows me attempting to save.. I've seen other posts talking about saving a dataUrl to Mongo so it seems like it should be possible since you guys are based off of Mongo. If I run a **.length**  on the dataUrl its 140,000+ characters long.